# Is there a way to get a default e-mail recipient by default when adding a new webform node?

Tags: webforms

When I add a new **Webform** node type, this have no e-mail recipien by default. You can read this message:

> Currently not sending e-mails, add an e-mail recipient below.

Is there a way to get a e-mail recipient value by default when creating a webform node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a custom module and hook_node_presave(). After you have a custom module created, you can use code like this to create a default e-mail configuration for any created Webforms.

Assuming your module were called myexample.module, the hook would look like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
 */
function myexample_node_presave($node) {
  // Add a default e-mail configuration for new nodes.
  if (empty($node->nid) && $node->type == 'webform') {
    $node->webform['emails'][] = array(
      'email' => 'example@example.com',
      'subject' => 'default',
      'from_name' => 'default',
      'from_address' => 'default',
      'template' => 'default',
      'excluded_components' => array(),
      'html' => 0,
      'attachments' => 0,
    );
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: `hook_node_presave` will execute before each `insert` and `update` operation, and after each update new `recipient` will attached to `webform`, so add `$node->is_new` to `if statement` or use `hook_node_insert`

Comment: Thanks it works as expected. Could I also set a default email template text, something like 'Hello, a message is sent from %title...' ?

Comment: I already get the default email template text by setting 'template' in the array. What about setting 'from_address' to the email component?

Comment: Adding $node->is_new isn't needed since I checked empty($node->nid). hook_node_insert() fires *after* the node has already been saved, so if you want webform to do the saving for you, it has to be in hook_node_presave().

You can set the email text by changing the "template" portion. Using the special word "default" will use the default webform template, as produced by the theme system and webform-mail.tpl.php. The same principle applies to from_name and from_address.

Comment: I would like to add that you might want to make sure that when you're doing this on hook_node_insert you need to make sure that your module is on a higher weight then the `webform` module, since it'll delete your e-mails elsewise. Hope this helps some others out, been at this for hours.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can.

You go to your webform node, click on "webform" then "email's", you should set up one if you don't have one, and on "E-mail to address" you can write your default email.
You can even set up the subject and the body.
You can print the whole email through %email_values token value, or field by field with label using  %email[yourfield] or without label using %value[yourfield].

I'm editing my answer:

You can set a defaul email recipient you have three choices:

1. You create an email field with a defaul value (your email) and the user can change that value;
2. create an email field with your email such as default value and click on "disable" if you don't want the user changes the email but he can still see it;
3. create a email field with your email such as default and click on "hidden", the user won't be able to see and change that email;

I hope this time will be useful :D

Comment: The OP is asking if you can automatically have the e-mail to address populated.  This doesn't answer his question.

Comment: I need the e-mail automatically added when I create the node.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer.

Comment: This still isn't a sufficient answer.  OP wants e-mail recipients automatically added at time of creation. He doesn't want to have to click through to Add an e-mail recipient every time.

I've taken a look at using `hook_node_insert`, but it doesn't seem to save the webform data at that point.  Might be worth checking out `hook_node_update`.

Comment: what about rules, can this be done with a rule?